# Obtaining controller Type from string action, string controller, object routeValues information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, how would I obtain the Type of the controller that would be used, given the information about the route: `string action, string controller, object routeValues`?

(The routeValues object might look like this new {area="admin"} and route to a controller for a different site area.)

Comment: What do you want achive? you could easily find out the Controllor from URL.

Comment: I can see using this to determine if a controller name string is actually a valid controller.  I'm trying to do just that -- I have a default "RedirectTo" controller from a home page that's stored in web.config.  I'd like to be able to first make sure it's a valid controller before blindly redirecting to it.

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box controller factory uses convention to find the controller type. I believe the convention is the controller name prepended to the word controller. For example if the controller name is 'home' then the type would be 'homecontroller'. By convention it is expecting to find this type in the controllers folder.

BTW, I believe the asp.net mvc code is open source. You can learn the exact conventions there.

Hope this helps.

Bob